# How to run a php script on confirm box ok event onclick of image?

Tags: javascript, php

On image click a confirm box is given and on confirm box ok event I want to run a php script.
I have done this but it is not working.
What else can i do..?

```
<html>
<body>
<img src='globe.jpg' style='margin-left:8.3cm;' onclick='
if(confirm("You want to unlist this notification..?"))
{
    <?php
    echo "Ok";
    ?>
}

else
{
    <?php
    echo "Cancel";
    ?>
}
'/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I dnt want to call php script on image click but what I want is: on image click one confirmation box and on ok event of confirmation I want to call php script. ok..??

Answer (score 1):

PHP is server side language! So you must do something on the server

Answer (score 0):

you can redirect on your php page with post data in query string and run your script in redirected file with checking of query string data or you can use click event with ajax so better to use redirect.

```
if(confirm("You want to unlist this notification..?"))
{
   window.location.href="my.php?id=ghf";
}
```

**Run your script in my.php**

Comment: your welcome :) always accept/upvote helpful answer